# Displaying information from unrelated nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model, nested-attributes

I'm building a Rails application with two models, both with a further two nested models:

Contacts -> Trackers -> Emails

and

Goals -> Stages -> Templates

I want to display information from a specific Goal on the show page of a particular Tracker but I'm struggling to get the right data to appear.

I have a field for goal_id in my Tracker parameters and I've added this line to my Tracker controller but I think I’m doing it wrong:

```
@goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
```

I'm sure it's going to be a really obvious mistake but I'm so new to Rails that I just can't seem to get it right and I'd love any suggestions you might have. Thanks in advance!

Model for Tracker:

```
class Tracker < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  has_one :goal
  has_many :emails, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Model for Goal:

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stages , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trackers
end
```

Controller for Tracker:

```
class TrackersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_contact
  before_action :set_tracker, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /trackers or /trackers.json
  def index
    @trackers = @contact.trackers
  end

  # GET /trackers/1 or /trackers/1.json
  def show
    @goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /trackers/new
  def new
    @tracker = @contact.trackers.build
  end

  # GET /trackers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /trackers or /trackers.json
  def create
    @tracker = @contact.trackers.build(tracker_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tracker.save
        format.html { redirect_to contact_trackers_path(@contact), notice: "Tracker was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tracker }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @tracker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /trackers/1 or /trackers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tracker.update(tracker_params)
        format.html { redirect_to contact_tracker_path(@contact), notice: "Tracker was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tracker }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @tracker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /trackers/1 or /trackers/1.json
  def destroy
    @tracker.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contact_trackers_path(@contact), notice: "Tracker was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def get_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
    end


    def set_tracker
      @tracker = @contact.trackers.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def tracker_params
      params.require(:tracker).permit(:name, :contact_id, :goal_id, :stage_id, :status, :note)
    end
end
```

Show page view for Tracker:

```
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Goal</h3>
    <%= @goals.name %>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your TrackersController you have:

```rb
  # GET /trackers/1 or /trackers/1.json
  def show
    @goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
  end
```

It looks like you're taking a Tracker **ID** and using that ID as the *ID of a Goal*.

It's unlikely that (using 709 as an example) Tracker 709, is associated with Goal 709, so this is very likely an error.  You do have an association between the models though, so you could use that to find the goal associated with the Tracker.

```rb
@goal = @tracker.goal
```

Note also in the above I'm using `@goal` not `@goals` since there's only one associated.  You'll need to update your view to also use `@goal`.  *Alternatively* in your view you could just access the goal directly via `@tracker.goal`; then you don't need to set `@goal` at all.

---

Potential model issues:  It looks like `Tracker has_one goal` and `Goal has_many trackers`.  This looks like you wanted a normal n-to-1 relationship.  So you probably want to change that `has_one` to a `belongs_to` instead.  (It doesn't imply ownership.)

As is you're telling Rails:

1. `Goal has_many trackers` -> the `trackers` table has a `goal_id` column that defines the relationship.
2. `Tracker has_one goal` -> the `goals` table has a `tracker_id` column that defines the relationship.

I don't know what migration(s) you've run, but you probably only want one of these two columns (`goal_id` and `tracker_id`).  You should take a look at your schema and fix this.  (You may also want to try using the [annotate_models](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) gem so you can easily see the columns in your tables.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the amazing and details explanation @tgf - the tracker.goal code has worked perfectly, along with changing the relationships in the models. My app is now working the way I want it and I really appreciate your help. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry for the follow up question, do you have any suggestions on how I would go about linking to the goal from the tracker from the tracker.goal code? I've tried a variety of link_to combinations but I'm struggling to get anywhere. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Cat, If you have the goal available as a variable called `goal` you can do something like: `<%= link_to "click here to view", goal %>`.  That's the simplest way. 
 Another way is to use a path helper.  First run `rails routes` to see your routes.  The first column is what's important.  You'll see something like `goals` for GET `index` and `goal` for GET `show` (as well as others).  We can append `_path` to those names to get a URL path helper which we'll use in the link like: `<%= link_to "click me", goal_path(goal.id) %>`